# How can I run CasperJS files in Android?

Tags: android, testing, terminal, casperjs, droidscript

How can I install and run CasperJS files in Android? Is it possible?

I would like to create an equal application [droidscript](http://droidscript.blogspot.com/) with test functions and execute on a webview.

Comment: I'm having similar use case now.  I have a JS application that also is encased in an android webview as an android app.  I have casper tests written for my JS application.  I want to be able to run these casper tests in an android webview env.  @fredericoallan, Did you figure out any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CasperJS is built on top of PhantomJS (and SlimerJS). Those are browsers themselves. They cannot be run in a WebView. It may be possible to compile, though I didn't find any documented trials.

You should be able to port the [PhantomJS API](http://phantomjs.org/api/) to an Android WebView and then make some adjustments to [CasperJS](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/) so that it uses this new API and can be run through DroidScript. This is a **big** task.

An easier task would be to keep a [PhantomJS/CasperJS instance](http://phantomjs.org/api/webserver/) running on a server (or spawn an instance from the server-side framework you would like to use) and query it with the specific scripts from your app. You can send all screenshots that are made to the app, but a live video view will not be possible.